# Writing the Laplacian matrix of directed graphs as product?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

The [Laplacian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of a nondirected graph can be written as $M^TM$ with $M$ being the incidence matrix of the graph. This makes the (otherwise tedious) proof of [Kirkhoff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) into a beautiful application of the [Cauchy-Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) (and indeed, this is one of the proofs in "Proofs from THE BOOK").

If the graph is directed, $M^TM$ does not work anymore; the diagonal of the resulting matrix contains the total degree of vertices, whereas for Kirkhoff's theorem to work, only the indegree should appear.

So my question is this: can this approach still be salvaged by a slightly different definition of $M$ that eludes me, or is the "tedious" proof necessary and Cauchy-Binet simply can't be used here?

Comment: In my test the product of incidence matrix and its tranpose is symmetric, but the adjacency matrix is not symmetric, which is really annoying me. So [the product is not equal to $D-A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262976/definition-of-laplace-matrix-using-incidence-matrix-and-degree-matrix), where $D$ is degree matrix. I am very confused about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe I have found a way to write the Laplacian as a product. First recall the definition in the directed-graph case: The Laplacian of $G=(V,E)$ is a matrix of size $|V|\times |V|$ such that $L_{ii}$ is the in-degree of $v_i$, and $L_{ij}$ for $i\ne j$ is minus the number of edges from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

Since the Laplacian needs not be symmetric in the directed case, it can't be written as $M^{T}M$. However, it can be written as $AB^T$ for two very similar matrices:

Define both A and B to be $n\times m$ matrices, where each row represents a vertex and each column represents an edge of $G$. Now, for each edge $e_k = v_i\to v_j$:

1. $A_{ik} = 1, A_{jk} = -1$
2. $B_{ik} = 0, B_{jk} = -1$

The rest of the entries are 0.

Unless I have some computational error, we have $L=AB^T$.

Comment: $n$ vertices, $m$ edges. Matrix $M$ is $n\times m$. Matrix $M^T$ is $m\times n$. So, $M^TM$ is which  a matrix $m\times n$ times $n\times m$. $M^TM$ should be $m\times m$. When you say incidence $M$, you should describe the $M_{ij}$ clearly. In [wikipedia Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix), $M$ is $m\times n$. each row represents an edge and each column represents an vertex of $G$. But you are wrong here.

Comment: By the way the incidence matrix $M$($m\times n$) in [wikipedia Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) is oriented incidence matrix. I read resources now (Jun 2019), $L$ can be symmetric.

Comment: The stuff about what I confused is for directed network $D-A\neq M_{ev}^TM_{ev}$, since $A$ is not symmetric, while $M_{ev}^TM_{ev}$ is symmetric. For undirected network, $M_{ev}^TM_{ev}=2(D-A)$. In my test, $D-A$ is never equal to $M_{ev}^TM_{ev}$. Here $M$ is $m\times n$ oriented incidence matrix. each row is edge, each column is vertex.

Comment: What do you mean  *$AB^T$ for two very similar matrices*. They mathematically similar or just looks similar?